# How is the sequence for X509Store.Certificates decided?

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, x509certificate

I am working with a cert store and am confused on how the certificates sequence is calculated.

As per documentation for [X509Store.Certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.certificates?view=net-7.0), it is mentioned in remark that

> This snapshot is recalculated each time the property is called, so the
> use of this property inside an iterative function is not recommended.

I wanted to know how is the sequence of certificates decided in the property.
I checked and it seems the sequence is not based on certificate issued to or issued date.
I have some execution that works directly with indexes of the certificates and wanted to confirm if I can guarantee the certificate I am working is correct.

Comment: Why would you depend on the index? The thumbprint uniquely identifies the cert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall not rely on certificate index in `X509Store.Certificates` collection because it is not deterministic and depends on certificate order in different sources which then combined into a resultant list. You shall use [X509Certificate2Collection.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.find?view=net-7.0) method to look for required certificate in the collection instead.